# Implicit derivation help? Please give me a hint (possibly a line #)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

ok so i am having trouble with finding the implicit derivative for this problem. I am doing it on an ipad and here is a screen shot of my work. A hint would better than a solution! Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Derivative on $R.H.S.$ is fine but on $L.H.S$, $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\left(\sqrt{xy}\right)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(xy\right)^{-1/2}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}(xy)}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

and $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}(xy)}{\mathrm{d}x}=y+xy'$$

Comment: ughh stupid error on my part, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Actually, you had it sort of right, but did not use parentheses. You do have the $y$ and the $y'x$.